# How does the Jacobian relate 3D to 2D?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

May be it is simple, but I'm on Google for hours without finding a clue. I'm reading an [article in computer vision](http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2011/proceedings/paper46/paper46.pdf) where the optical flow equation is $\nabla I\cdot v + {dI \over dt} = 0 $ and for the 3D version it is $\nabla  I\cdot [J_\pi V]+{dI \over dt}=0$

I understand most of the paper but this sentence "where the associated 3D displacement of a point is related to the motion of its projection by the $2 \times 3$  Jacobian matrix $J_\pi={\partial p \over \partial P}$ "

$P$ is a 3D point and $p$ is a 2D one, $v$ is 2d vector and $V$ is a 3D one, $\pi$ is the projection matrix (I think), I don't understand this Jacobian part, thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

---

**EDIT:** Link to the original article has been added.

Comment: Jacobian matrix usually shows up when you are using the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix) in higher dimensions. They also show up when you change coordinate systems. It might be helpful if you could give us more context, or even link the original article here.

Comment: @Braindead Thanks for your reply, I believe it is a change of coordinates as the we are talking about 3D motion vector and it's projection on the 2D plane, but then why the jacobian does contains partial derivatives instead of a normal transformation matrix ? the paper name "Scene flow from depth and color images" Letouzy et al

Comment: In the future, if you are asking about an article, try to include the link to the original article in the question post. Looking at the original article clarified a lot of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I$ is a function on the photograph, $R^2\times R$. It depends both on the position on the 2-D screen and time.

The map $\pi$ in your article is a map from $R^3 \to R^2,$ not necessarily a matrix, or even a ["projection" in the sense used by mathematicians.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28mathematics%29)

> **Technical Note:** There is actually a subspace $M\subset R^3$ where $M$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $R^3$, which is possibly time-dependent. The paper assumes that this map $\pi$ is a smooth diffeomorphism when restricted to the $M$ onto a subspace of $R^2$.

$V$ is a time-dependent vector field on $R^3$. (Or $M$.)

$v$ is the induced vector field on $R^2$ by $\pi.$ (Actually, only on the image of $M$ through $\pi$.)

A vector $V$ at the point $P$ on $M$ can be thought of as a derivative of a path based at the point $P$.

Heuristically,

$V = \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (P + Vt +O(t^2))$

How does this give you a vector in $R^2$? A path in $M$ turns into a path in $R^2$ by the map $\pi$. And we can take the derivative of the induced path:

$v = \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \pi(P + Vt +O(t^2)) = (D\pi_P V)$

The right hand side ($D\pi_P$) represents the [total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of $\pi$ at $P$.

> **Technical Note 2:** The whole bit about $\pi$ being one-to-one was so that you  actually get a well-defined vector field on the image. If $\pi$ isn't one to one, then a point $p$ could have two different pre-images, and there could be two different vectors at those two different pre-images.

Because $\pi$ was a function from $R^3$ into $R^2$, $D\pi_P$ can be represented by a Jacobian matrix of dimension $2\times 3$ matrix:

$\pi(x,y,z) = ( u(x,y,z), v(x,y,z))$, where $u$ and $v$ and the horizontal and the vertical components of the function $\pi$. Then,

$J_\pi = \left[\begin{matrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} \\ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial z}\end{matrix}\right]$

Notice that $P = (x,y,z)$ and $p = \pi(P) = (u,v)$. Therefore, the notation $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial P}$ makes sense.

In short, $D\pi_P = J_\pi = \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial P}$ essentially represent the same exact thing (the latter two expressions are a little bit sloppy with the base point), and

$$ v = J_\pi V$$ by definition.

So basically, the two equations are identical. The only difference is whether you think of the equation in terms of the 2-dimensional vector field $v$ or in terms of the 3-dimensional vector field $V$. But $v$ allows you to recover $V$, so it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response, one last question though, what is O(t2) ?

Comment: It is called the [Big O](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation. It is a way of saying things that are like (t^2) or higher order.

Comment: Essentially, if I just wrote $P + tV$, that would be a straight line going through $P$ in the direction of vector $V$. However, the straight line might not be actually part of the 3D object you are taking the image of. The $O(t^2)$ portion is some function basically what allows my line to "curve" in a way that it would fit on the 3D object, and it doesn't effect the value of the derivative at $t=0$.